# Controlling the unit labels in APS/Forge model derivative units

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

I'm using the model derivative api to extract some revit parameter data. In the properties for the model, I'm a little confused on how the units are determined. For example in this Ceiling property:

```json
"Dimensions": {
    "Volume": "13.236 CF",
    "Area": "50.827 ft^2",
    "Perimeter": "28.573 ft-and-fractional-in",
    "Slope": "0.000 °"
},
```

is it possible to change the perimeter unit labels to something besides `ft-and-fractional-in`?

The only reference to this unit label that I could find is in [this article](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/setting-measure-command-units-api-forge-viewer).

Answer (score 0):

The blog post you shared is about the units used by measure extension.

The units from the properties of the converted design are defined by the Revit Project units, as describet in [this lightning talk](https://youtu.be/GgW9gBCRrWg?t=206)